# Mips error printing length of string

Tags: string, count, mips

This seems like it should work but clearly doesn't. When I try to count the length of the string it returns some crazy long number. When I one step the program it works fine but prints out the wrong number. Can somebody point me back on track so that I can work on the next function? I just need to figure out what is throwing off the count

```
############################################
# Program Name: strings.s
# Programmer: David Bierbrauer
# Date: 9/07/2017
############################################
# Functional Description:
#
#
############################################
# Cross References:
#
#
############################################

    .data   # Data declaration section
stringa: .asciiz "Enter the first string: "
stringb: .asciiz "\nEnter the second string: "
    .text

main:   # Start of code section

    #li $v0, 4      #get first string input
    la $a0, stringa
    jal read
    jal length
    jal print  
                #get second string input
    la $a0, stringb
    jal read
    jal length
    jal print
    j end


length:
    li $t0, -1  #loop count 0
    j lengthloop
lengthloop:     #exit address $s1
    lb $t1, 0($a0)      #load next char into $t1
    beqz $t1, endlength
    addi $a0, $a0, 1    #increment string pointer
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    #increment count
    j lengthloop
endlength:
    jr $ra


equality:
    lb $t2, 0($a0)
    lb $t3, 0($a1)
    bne $t2,$t3 notequal

append:

print:
    li $v0, 1
    la 
    syscall
    jr $ra
read:
    li $v0, 4
    syscall #print prompt

    li $v0,9
    li $a0,80
    syscall
    move $a0,$v0

    li $v0,8
    li $a1,80
    syscall

    jr $ra
end:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted doesn't even assemble, because there's a stray `la` in the `print` routine.

Aside from that, your `length` routine returns the length in `$t0`, while your `print` routine assumes that the value is in `$a0`. That's why you get the wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` looks odd. `spim` yells at me - bad syntax of `la` pseudoinstruction. I guess, you mean

```
print:
    li $v0, 1
    la $a0, 0($t0)
    syscall
    jr $ra
```